# Spring, Hibernate, JPA - Why am i not using entity manager, why does casacdeType.Persist only work with entity manager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I was testing out how cascade works, and ran into some stuff that confuses me. I have two simple entities:

```
@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "JOINCOLMN", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    Person person;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Child child;

}
```

I was testing out the cascade type persist. So i wrote this piece of code:

```
Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(100L);
        person.setName("SomeName");
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setId(60L);
        child.setPerson(person);
        personRepository.save(person);
```

However, even though both of them were suppose to get persisted, only the person gets persist. So the first question is :

- Why is this not working?

I searched around a bit, and found people using the Hibernate entity manager. Here is an example where the persist cascade type works:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

Author a = new Author();
a.setFirstName(“John”);
a.setLastName(“Doe”);

Book b1 = new Book();
b1.setTitle(“John’s first book”);
a.getBooks().add(b1);

Book b2 = new Book();
b2.setTitle(“John’s second book”);
a.getBooks().add(b2);

em.persist(a);

em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

My second question is:

- I can see that entity manager is used to manage the transaction, and manage the entities. But i never use it, so what happens in my piece of the code? Who manages the transaction? Who persist the entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring JPA can help you manage your transaction by using repositories, or the @Transactional annotation. It basically wraps any method so the core of the method is performed in a transaction.
In your case, the call `personRepository.save(person)` opens a transaction and commits the changes to the database.

Regarding your first question, the problem comes from your `@OneToOne` relationship and its setters implementation. Calling `child.setPerson(person);` does not set the person's child. Therefore, when calling `personRepository.save(person)` , as the person's child is null, there is no Child object to persist.

You want to make sure to keep the object state coherent:

```
Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(100L);
        person.setName("SomeName");
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setId(60L);
        child.setPerson(person);
        person.setChild(child);
        personRepository.save(person);
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot. I will look more into the `@Transactional` annotation to get a better understanding. Just a quick extra question. If i wrap the method that contains the code i wrote above in a `@Transactional`, when will the transaction start? Will the transaction start when the method is started? What will happen when it reaches personRepository.save(person), since you said that that method also opens a transaction and commits the changes ?

Comment: The transaction would start just before the method is started if it does not already exists. When reaching another `@Transactional` method or a repository method, nothing would happen as the code is already executed inside a transaction. Note that you can also annotate a class with @Transactional (it has the same effect as annotating all the class' methods).